# Terraform Unexpected EOF

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I'm getting ***Unexpected EOF*** on Terraform Apply even when there is nothing wrong with code.
I tested the same Code on my Personal Laptop and it works Perfectly fine , while on my Work Laptop it fails with Above error on any random resource creation on GCP

Terraform version :

```
Terraform v1.0.2
on windows_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/google v4.46.0
```

I have same version on both laptops , not sure what is causing this error. Only other thing differ in my work laptop is I have to set Custom Certs for gcloud config due to security concerns .
I have set those with below command

```
 gcloud config set core/custom_ca_certs_file
```

update :

Error in Terraform :

```
    google_compute_health_check.autohealing[0]: Creating...
google_compute_health_check.autohealing[0]: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
google_compute_health_check.autohealing[0]: Creation complete after 11s [id=projects/terraform-101-370721/global/healthChecks/auto-health-check]
╷
│ Error: Error creating ResourcePolicy: unexpected EOF
│
│   with google_compute_resource_policy.daily_backup,
│   on instance_group.tf line 74, in resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "daily_backup":
│   74: resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "daily_backup" {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: Error creating Network: unexpected EOF
│
│   with google_compute_network.network[0],
│   on network.tf line 3, in resource "google_compute_network" "network":
│    3: resource "google_compute_network" "network" {
│
╵
```

Note :
Code block :

```
resource "google_compute_resource_policy" "daily_backup" {
  name   = "every-day-4am"
  region = local.reg
  snapshot_schedule_policy {
    schedule {
      daily_schedule {
        days_in_cycle = 1
        start_time    = "04:00"
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "google_compute_network" "network" {
  count =  var.flip.set_ntw == true ? 1 : 0
  name                    = var.ntw.name
  auto_create_subnetworks = var.ntw.auto_create_sub
  mtu                     = var.ntw.ntw_mtu
}
```

Even the error is on different resource every time I freshly run apply.

Also, same code won't give any EOF on my Personal PC

Comment: I think the issue is the line-endings of the file. Maybe one is Windows endling line (DOS) and other Unix line ending https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~krueger/csc209h/tut/line-endings.html

Comment: I already checked encoding , also both of my Laptops have Windows 10 .Still code will run on one and fails on the other

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the entire error message exactly as Terraform printed it? I'm hoping that some of the other context in the error message will give some clues as to whether it's Terraform Core or a Terraform provider plugin that is returning this error, and hopefully therefore narrow down what it could be referring to.

Comment: Could you please print out the complete error message and some relative construct of your code to narrow down the issue?